# Apache 403 - looking .htaccess in parent's parent directory

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I am having this problem (apache2, ubuntu 12.04)

I have put all my sites in /home/username/vhosts folder
I have added permissions to home and username to be x and chmod -r 777 on vhosts
Added /etc/hosts to access my sites with desired names
Did a2enmod rewrite

But still I have this error:

```
[Sat Jun 23 00:05:23 2012] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/username/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
```

WHY is it not readable? I did

```
sudo -s
su - www-data
```

and with that I can correctly list the /home/username dir

What is wrong with me or apache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out if apache can access (+x) the /home, /home/user AND /home/user/vhost folder, as it normally checks the .htaccess down the tree.

Comment: You're probably more correct than me as it looks like the OP has bodged their error message.

Comment: No I didn't: [Sat Jun 23 00:05:22 2012] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/wade/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable
[Sat Jun 23 00:05:23 2012] [crit] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: /home/wade/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable

Comment: You can try this (for test) chmod a+x /home; chmod a+x /home/wade

Comment: @Basil: what are the permissions on /home/wade/.htaccess ? ( `ls -l /home/wade/.htaccess` )

Comment: Did so. Nothing. How can I correctly pretend being apache? Is the way I use ok?

Comment: @lain, I haven't got this file... WAIT A MOMENT!!! I HAVE IT! It was empty with incorrect permissions! I have deleted it and VOILA! it works!! thank you, Lain (Iwakura? )

Answer (score 1):

I guess the permissions on the .htaccess file are incorrect try

```
chmod +r /home/username/.htaccess
```

Comment: Also check if apache can enter /home/username directory.

Comment: @AndrewSmith: The error message the OP posted says `/home/username/.htaccess` ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how can I check it? I used "sudo -s su - www-data" commands to pretend to be www-data, and I can list all three dirs. Any other ways to check that? **lain**, yes, it does.

Comment: I have no .htaccess in /home/username. Do I have to have it?

Comment: Erm Look at the error message you posted... It's late where you are - go to bed it'll be easier in the morning.

Comment: To go to sleep was probably the best advice out there, thanks again :)